# How to get/delete all relationships from a node using node-neo4j?

Tags: node.js, neo4j, node-neo4j

I need to delete a node from a neo4j db but according to the docs all the node's relationships have to be deleted first, so guess I need to get the list of those relationships and then delete them one by one.  node.getRelationships(type) returns relationships of a particular type -- but not all relationships of all types.  Passing '*' for the type doesn't work.

Is there a simpler way to delete a node, or get a list of relationships?

It looks fairly easy to do this directly in cypher so I can always fall back on that, but I'd like to use the node-neo4j library if possible.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you pass `node.delete(force=true)` for the node? Otherwise, you can call the `node.all()` function to get all the relationships.

Sorry if the syntax looks wrong, JS/CS is not my native language.

Comment: The docs (http://coffeedoc.info/github/thingdom/node-neo4j/master/) recommend not using force=true, but all() does seem to work -- the key is to pass it null for the 'type' param.  Thanks!